# Is it possible to cast a parent object to a child object in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and as the title states, I'm trying to cast a parent object to one of its children. For example, I have a class Operation and then a few subclasses of Operation (we'll call them `OpA`, `OpB`, `OpC`). I want to do something like this:

```
Operation* op;

switch(someCondition)
{
    case 0:
        op = new OpA;
        break;
    case 1:
        op = new OpB;
        break;
    case 2:
        op = new OpC;
        break
}
```

(Hopefully that makes sense). Is this possible in C++? I am most familiar with Swift which has a very straightforward `ObjectA as ObjectB` casting operator, if that further clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Thanks!

Edit: I didn't do a great job phrasing my question at all haha. Currently, my code just looks like this:

```
Operation* op;    

op = new OpA(parameter);

op->functionOfOpA();
```

I'm getting an error that the Operation class doesn't have a member named functionOfOpA(), which is correct. If this was working as I would expect it to, op would now point to an OpA object that would have functionOfOpA().

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Your example code shows casting a child to a parent pointer, which is implicit.
Casting from a parent pointer to a child should almost always be done with `dynamic_cast`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I have, yes. I tried using dynamic_cast as dave suggested, but don't think I'm quite understanding how it's used properly.

Comment: @dave Ah! I might've gotten my question backwards, my apologies...  dynamic_cast is what I had attempted to use, but I don't think I had it quite right.

Comment: @dave The example shows no casting. A cast is an *explucit* type conversion.

Comment: FWIW, use of base class and derived class is better than use of parent class and child class.

Comment: You can cast almost anything to almost anything else in C++. The result may or may not be usable, but cast you can. However if you find yourself casting, you are likely not doing proper OO programming (you decide whether it's bad or not).

Comment: dynamic_cast is for dynamic type (run time pointer type) and the static_cast is for the static type. For example if we have, A* a = new B() (where B is a subclass of A) the static type of a is A and the dynamic type is B. You can cast a pointer using dynmic_cast if the dynamic type is compatible with it.

Comment: It is unclear what the probem with the example code is.

Comment: @n.m. I did such a poor job explaining this, I'm so sorry haha. Just updated the original post to include more specific detail.

Comment: The second fragment is something a lot of people expect to be able to do in C++ for some reason. Inheritance is meant to support OOP. This pattern is the exact opposite of OOP. You simply have a broken design. You can try and patch it with casts and whatnot, but it will bite you. If you want to fix your design, you should ask a question about *your design*, not about casts.

Comment: @n.m. Interesting, I obviously have some design fundamentals that I'm missing out on as I would've assumed this was actually good design!

Comment: In your example, why is op an Operation and nit an OpA? If you can declare it as OpA, just do so. If you cannot for one readon or another, then there is a serious problem in there somewhere. The essence of OOP in one sentence is "the object knows its exact type, so the rest of the world doesn't need to".

Comment: @n.m. My full intention is to have op and then a lot of logic that is related to op. However, depending on specific cases, op needs to be OpA or OpB or OpC even though the logic following is the same. Does that make sense?

Comment: (Cont) So in your example you create an object. Then you forget about its exact type (remember just the base class), which is perfectly fine. Then you try to recall the exact type to call its method, and this last operation is very problematic. We try to avoid it at all costs in OOP. These margins are too small to write down a detailed explanation why. Of course if you are not doing OOP at all, then these considerations do not apply.

Comment: (Cont) Long story short, the rule of thumb is: if you find yourself switching on the actual dynamic type of your object, you should move the whole thing to a virtual function of your base class, and just call it. Derived classes implement just their respective branches of the switch. Of course there are nuances and problems and what have you.

Comment: @n.m. That makes sense. I appreciate your detailed response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to cast a parent object to a child object in C++?

It is possible to cast a reference or a pointer to parent into a reference or point to a derived class, if the referred object is an instance of that derived type. This is called downcasting.

There are two options:

- `static_cast` can be used if you know for certain that the an object of the derived type. If it isn't then using `static_cast` results in undefined behaviour, so don't use it unless you can prove that it is correct.
- `dynamic_cast` can be used even if you aren't sure of the actual derived type. It will result in null pointer, or an exception in case of a reference if the object turns out to not be of the appropriate type. `dynamic_cast` may only be used if the object is polymorphic (at least one virtual member function).

However, downcasting is usually not a good solution, and it is often best to look for another solution to why you think you might need it. Typically, the correct solution is a virtual function.

---

> want to do something like this:

You can do exactly that (what you do in the example), assuming `Operation` is a base of `OpA`, `OpB` and `OpC`. Note that the destructor of `Operation` should be virtual or else `delete op` would have undefined behaviour.

Note that no downcasting is involved in your example. You're converting pointers to derived into pointers to base. This conversion is implicit, is called upcasting, and is always safe.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful answer! If I'm understanding you correctly, the code as I wrote it should work as expected?

Comment: @KevinForté as long as the assumptions that I listed are met, then yes.

Comment: I just added some more clarification to my original question, as I'm still running into a minor issue. I feel as though I am misunderstanding a key concept here haha.

Answer (score 1):

While your *actual* question already is [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57874290/1312382), consider a design such that you do not need down-casts at all:

```
class Operation
{
public:
    virtual ~Operation() { } // as mentioned already:
                             // you should add a virtual destructor

    virtual void functionOfOperation() = 0; // having a general name...
};
```

By providing a virtual function, you allow deriving classes to override a function in the base class, i. e. to modify the behaviour of the function according to its own needs. In above example the function is pure virtual, i. e. doesn't provide an implementation, which likely wouldn't be meaningful anyway. This makes the class abstract, i. e. you cannot create instances of a pure `Operation` class, only of derived types. These *need* to override pure virtual functions, otherwise they remain abstract, too.

```
class OpA
{
public:
    void functionOfOperation() override
    {
        // appropriate implementation
    }
};
```

`override` keyword is not mandatory, but very useful to detect errors if signatures in base and derived class do not match (either because base class' version changed later or simply because of having been inattendent...), so it is good practice.

```
Operation* op = new OpA();
op->functionOfOperation(); // will call OpA's variant
```

To illustrate difference between virtual and non-virtual functions:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { }

    void normalFunction()
    { std::cout << "normal (base)" << std::endl; }
    virtual void virtualFunction()
    { std::cout << "virtual (base)" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void normalFunction()
    { std::cout << "normal (derived)" << std::endl; }
    void virtualFunction() override
    { std::cout << "virtual (derived)" << std::endl; }
};
```

Note that you cannot apply `override` keyword to non-virtual functions! Non-virtual functions don't override base class' functions, they only *hide* them:

```
Derived* derived = new Derived();
Base* base = derived;

base->normalFunction();    // outputs "normal (base)"
base->virtualFunction();   // outputs "virtual (derived)" (!)
derived->normalFunction(); // outputs "normal (derived)"

delete base; // due to virtual destructor, we can use either base or derived...
```